# Copying Virtual Machine While Running

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

Should I shutdown a virtual machine before copying it to an external drive.  We are looking to copy all the contents of our storage device to an external drive since we are going to be adding more drives to it.  Many of the files are the virtual machine and VHD files for our Hyper-V server.  Would there be any issue in copying these files while the Virtual Servers are still running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SImple like that. You can not do that while the virtual servers are running.

That is a Server 2012 / Hyper-V v3 feature.

So, it is not a question of "should you shut down", but "how do you want to do that without"?

Only chance now is stuff like "replication on the partition level" that can be done transparently, then broken again. But a file copy is out.

Comment: That is what I thought, that is wouldn't even let me transfer it in the first place.  But on the slight chance it did, I thought i would ask.  Thank you.

Comment: @Patrick Push for an upgrade to 2012 - it is a MUCH better hypervisor and it HAS this ability, too. It also scales better and is a lot faster in IO (with the new vhdx file format). And safer.

Comment: the reason we are making these backups is because we are adding more disks to our SAN for our new server.  The new server is going to be Server 2012 Hyper V, and will be our first upgrade point.  The rest of the network will be upgraded by the end of the summer.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Great. Server 2012 is a GREAT step forward for you then - I wont nag about the SERVER side, but the Hyper-V side is terrific, including the new file share abilities (run a VM with the VHDX files hosted on a file share). Make sure you upgrade your disc format by converting the vhd files to vhdx.

Answer (score 2):

You should shutdown the VMs before copying the VHD files. It is possible to copy them while Hyper-V is running by snapshotting the VM (the bas VHDs are locked by Hyper-V for both read/write when there are no snapshots, but only write-locked when there are snapshots).

There is a reasonably good chance of corrupting the VM if you copy the VHD file without shutting it down first. What gets corrupted is extremely hard to say. Databases are commonly corrupted by copying their files without "notifying" the DBMS about the snapshot (and in most cases it easiest to simply shutdown the system).

Similar file corrupt can occur with files that are critical for starting the VMs as well, the registry is a database too. I've seen plenty of other odd problems from this, though it's a roll of the dice.

In any case, the prime rule of backups applies, if you haven't tried restoring from a backup then you should always assume the backup failed. Until you've restore the VMs on the new drives make sure to keep the old ones in workable order...

Comment: +0 Correct except IIRC there is a mechanism at least in Windows CLIENTS that get notified when VSS on the HOST is active. VSS is also used for "whole hyper-v server backups", you know. And corrupt databases aer not somethign that would accept. Btw., any decent database would roll back, not become corrupt.

Comment: None of that is new to me. Making assumptions about someone else's systems and applications working in a reliable or logical manor is begging for disappointment.

Comment: Not really. Because this same mechanism is used for backups. And you do like backups, or?

Comment: This questions isn't asking about making regular backups or using backup software... It's asking about making a copy of VHD files.

Comment: Same thing though. COrrupt DB is corrupt DB, like it or not.